# Bootstrap 3 column issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with `bootstrap 3`, and am new to it but it seems like a fairly simple transition from 2.

Here is the jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/AHvLW/

And here is an image of how it renders when they are all in col-md-4:

[image]

I don't get it though, it works fine in jsFiddle, but not on my index file. Anyone experience a similar issue of might know whats up with it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the columns are not all equal in height you need to add a clearfix `<div>` for the large viewports just as the new row should start, that is between your 3rd and 4th column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>

    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/AHvLW/4/show/)**

Comment: Boom. You're the man! I've heard a lot about clearfix but have not really read about it. I believe I now should. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

You can easily solve it with this css :

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: left;
}
```

Found this solution [here](http://www.bluthemes.com/blog/3/clearing-bootstrap-3-columns)

Comment: This is the best solution, especially if you're populating the page dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand why there isn't a bootstrap class that does this automatically. When you consider the amount of bloat bootstrap does have. The class could be applied to a row with a specific class for example: `.row-uniform .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) { cle` ... for example.

Answer (score 2):

not an answer to your question, but you should be able to optimize your code since there is no need to use all size classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>

    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is true for the columns but unfortunately the responsive utility classes `visible-X` are not optimized to work the same way, for the clearfix you do need to add both medium and large sizes

Comment: you are right (updated), there's some discussion about it already. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your div tags are closed correctly and the classes that you are using have correctly referenced in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution where you don't mind all three columns being of equal height, and you can't use a wrapper due to calling different column numbers per different screen sizes you can apply a rule similar to my solution where I apply an id to a main wrapper of the columns and then style the column size to have a minimum height.

```
main#shop .col-md-3 {
    min-height:600px;
}
```

Comment: *Also, use a media query.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this may help some people. Just add the following to your stylesheet. I have provided CSS or SCSS.

### css

```
/*================ Row Uniform ==================*/
.row-uniform {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.row-uniform:after {
  clear: both;
}
.row-uniform:before {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}
.row-uniform .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.row-uniform .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.row-uniform .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.row-uniform .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .row-uniform .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .row-uniform .col-md-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-md-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-uniform .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .row-uniform .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

### scss

```
/*================ Row Uniform ==================*/

.row-uniform {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  &:after {
    clear:both;

  }
  &:before {
    display: table;
    content: '';
  }

  // 2
  .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  // 3
  .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  // 4
  .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  // 6
  .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  // sm
  @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px) {
    // 2
    .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 3
    .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 4
    .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 6
    .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
  }
  // md
  @media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1200px) {
    // 2
    .col-md-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 3
    .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 4
    .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 6
    .col-md-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
  }
  // lg
  @media (min-width:1200px) {
    // 2
    .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 3
    .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 4
    .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
    // 6
    .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1) {
      clear: left;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you just give your rows the new class row-uniform.

```
<div class="row-uniform">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  </div>
</div>
```